# EF Core 2.2 scaffold existing database and lazyloading

Tags: dotnet-cli, ef-core-2.2

Looking at the docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Its not apparent that if you use the existing Db approach AND want to use lazyloading, whether or not you have to manually edit each entity as virtual that you want to use as a related entity.  Really?  Am I missing something?

Is there no other way to use an existing Db AND lazyloading?

I tried the method using proxies, but the scaffolding tool does not mark the related entities as virtual.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to manually edit each entity.

`DbContext` scaffold commands generate all navigation properties as `virtual`, so they are "ready" for [lazy loading via proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading).

So in order to use it, all you need is to activate it as explained in the documentation

> The simplest way to use lazy-loading is by installing the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/) package and enabling it with a call to `UseLazyLoadingProxies`